# How store an object in Dynamodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I understand that to put an item into a Dynamodb table it has to be in a structure like this but is there an option to be able to input a standard Javascript object without this special structure? If not, is there an existing function in the AWS SDK that would convert my Javascript object into one with this special structure for Dynamodb?

```
var params = {
  Item: {
   "AlbumTitle": {
     S: "Somewhat Famous"
    }, 
   "Artist": {
     S: "No One You Know"
    }, 
   "SongTitle": {
     S: "Call Me Today"
    }
  }, 
  ReturnConsumedCapacity: "TOTAL", 
  TableName: "Music"
 };
```

Comment: Checkout DocumentClient

Comment: Another option is that you put only the info in attributes that you need to look up the items or for use in secondary indexes. All the other data goes into a JSON attribute on the item. DynamoDB is way more efficient this way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The AWS SDK does provide a few ways to do this.

The one I am familiar with is the `AWS.DynamoDB.Converter`. It can be used like so

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

let record = {
   "AlbumTitle": "Somewhat Famous", 
   "Artist": "No One You Know", 
   "SongTitle": "Call Me Today"
}

// Your DynamoDB representation
let ddbRecord = AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.marshall(record)

/* ddbRecord is now
{ 
  AlbumTitle: { S: 'Somewhat Famous' },
  Artist: { S: 'No One You Know' },
  SongTitle: { S: 'Call Me Today' } 
}
*/
```

To inverse the operation you would use the `unmarshall` function. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/Converter.html

---

Alternatively there is a `DocumentClient` available but I havent used it. The documentation on it is quite good https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-the-amazon-dynamodb-document-client-in-the-aws-sdk-for-javascript/

Comment: Ok, thank you! DocumentClient is what I was looking for.